# Salvar alterações no banco

Tags: c#, mysql

Estou tentando alterar os dados salvos no Banco, Basicamente quando clico duas vezes no `DataGrid` ele povoa os meus `TextBoxs` para efetuar as alterações no banco, porém quando eu clico pra salvar ele da o seguinte erro. Detalhe esse erro só acontece quando adiciono mais um valor ao `txtPreco`, se eu apagar o que estava inserido e colocar outro valor ele cadastra um novo produto (o que não é pra acontecer quando vou editar)

aqui a foto do banco de dados

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esse é o meu código que estou utilizando para tentar alterar os dados cadastrados no banco

```
  //criando a bool
        bool informacoesSalvas = false;

        private void btnSalvar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtNome.Text))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O nome do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
            return; // sai do método
        }
        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPreco.Text))
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("O Preço do produto está vazio, por favor digite algo");
            return;
        }

        else if (informacoesSalvas)
        {

            // Abre a conexão
            conectar.Open();

            //Query SQL
            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Produto (Nome,Descricao,Preco)" +
            "VALUES('" + txtNome + "','" + txtDescricao.Text + "','" + txtPreco.Text + "' )", conectar);

            //Executa a Query SQL
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Fecha a conexão
            conectar.Close();

            //Mensagem de Sucesso
            MessageBox.Show("Alterado com Sucesso!", "Informação", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            informacoesSalvas = true;
        }
        else
        {
            conectar.Open();
            //Convertendo

            Converter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);

            //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, `status`) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";

            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@peca", txtNome.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nome", txtDescricao.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantidade", txtPreco.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataentrada", ckbAtiv.Checked);

            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto Cadastrado", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creio que se problema não seja com seu código, mas sim na inserção do seu banco. Há algo de errado com sua coluna 'Preco', pode ser que essa coluna não exista na sua tabela atual ou você esteja tentando inserir algum tipo de variável que não seja aceita pelo tipo da sua coluna, por exemplo, adicionar uma string em uma coluna do tipo double. Você checou essas informações que eu mencionei?

Comment: Que valor vai no texto `txtPreco.Text`? Na base de dados a coluna `Preco` é de que tipo?

Comment: A base de dados da coluna `Preco` é double, vou colocar uma foto do banco de dados

Comment: Qual o valor da propriedade `Inserir.CommandText`?E mostre a linha em que passa o parâmetro `@Preco`.

Comment: @AugustoVasques não entendi muito bem, estou iniciando em C# ainda. poderia explicar um pouco melhor

Comment: Ali na imagem está dando erro em `Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery()` eu quero saber o valor da propriedade `CommandText` do objeto `Inserir`.

Comment: Creio eu que seja isso ? 

`Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, `status`) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";`

Comment: Também gostaria de ver a linha em `Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValues(...` onde o primeiro parâmetro é `@Preco`

Comment: Está ai o erro :`Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, status) VALUES (@peca, @nome, @quantidade, @dataentrada)";` os parâmetros não batem

Comment: Opa vou tentar aqui pra ver como desenrola

Comment: Precisa ser colocado na mesma ordem ?

Comment: sim e tem que ser compatíveis.

Comment: ok, estou modificando e vou compilar pra ver como desenrola, obrigado @AugustoVasques

Comment: @AugustoVasques bom ele começou a somente cadastrar o produto, ainda nao consigo fazer salvar as alterações

Comment: Você tem que abrir uma [transação de dados](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.begintransaction?view=netframework-4.7.2) inserir no banco de dados usar o comando [commit](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction.commit?view=netframework-4.7.2) e só assim ele grava no banco de dados.

Comment: Eu sou meio novo, pode me dar um exemplo de como fazer isso ?

Comment: @AugustoVasques, o exemplo que você apresentou ficou bom, e estou utilizando, porem ele ainda somente cadastra, resolvi fazer ele em outro botão mas deu outro erro, segue o link do outro erro [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/371435/como-alterar-um-dado-no-bd)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom pessoal foi assim que consegui resolver esse problema, agora já esta alterando no banco

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        lblID.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
        txtNome.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txtDescricao.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txtPreco.Text = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
        alterar = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());


        Converter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);

    }

    private void btnSalvar2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlConnection conectar = new MySqlConnection("server=127.0.0.1;database=ProdPacote; Uid=root; pwd=1234;");
        conectar.Open();
        var transaction = conectar.BeginTransaction();
        if (alterar <= 0)
        {
            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Produto (Nome, Descricao, Preco, `status`) VALUES (@Nome, @Descricao, @Preco, @status)";

            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nome", txtNome.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Descricao", txtDescricao.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Preco", txtPreco.Text);
            Inserir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@status", ativIndat);
            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();

            transaction.Commit();
            conectar.Close();
            MessageBox.Show("Produto cadastrado", "Concluido",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK,
            MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();

        }
        else
        {
            conectar.Close();
            conectar.Open();
            //Convertendo

            Converter = Convert.ToDecimal(txtPreco.Text);

            //MessageBox.Show("Conectado");

            MySqlCommand Inserir = new MySqlCommand();
            Inserir.Connection = conectar;
            Inserir.CommandText = "UPDATE  Produto SET Nome = '"+txtNome.Text+"', Descricao = '"+txtDescricao.Text+"', Preco ="+Converter+", status = "+ativIndat +" WHERE ID_Produto ="+alterar+" ";


            Inserir.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conectar.Close();
            alterar = 0;
            txtNome.Text = "";
            txtPreco.Text = "";
            txtDescricao.Text = "";
            MessageBox.Show("Produto alterado", "Concluido",
              MessageBoxButtons.OK,
              MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            selecionarCategoria();


        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Usando um fragmento de seu exemplo para mostrar o uso do BeginTransaction e Commit.

**nota:** eu copiei exatamente o mesmo conteúdo da pergunta.

```
    conectar.Open();

    //inicia a transação de dados
    var transaction = conectar.BeginTransaction();


    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("INSERT INTO Produto (Nome,Descricao,Preco)" +
    "VALUES('" + txtNome + "','" + txtDescricao.Text + "','" + txtPreco.Text + "' )", conectar);

    //insere os dados.
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // Fecha a transação de dados salvando as alterações efetuadas
    transaction.Commit();


    conectar.Close();
```